# How do I find an array and make it stop if I found that array already?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that prints "Found" if the element I want to search is in the array. However, it doesn't seem to do that. What can I do with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int size;
    int elemArr;

    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int arr[size];

    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
        printf("Integer #%d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Element to search in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &elemArr);

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if(arr[i]==elemArr){
            printf("Found!");
            break;
        }else{
            printf("Not Found!");
            break;     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain the loop where you search for the value in the array to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially, if the condition `arr[i]==elemArr` is false, what happens then? And think about when you can definitely say that the element isn't in the array, can you really do it while still searching for the element?

Comment: if the first element you're looking at is the one you want, print found and break, if not, print not found and break. You'll only ever check the 1st element, because you'll break out whatever happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wrong, basically you'll want to iterate over the whole array in order to find the desired number, and only in the case that you didn't find it you'd want to print "Not Found" and possibly return non-zero integer to indicate error. One way to do it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(arr[i] == elemArr){
        printf("Found!");
        return 0;
    }
}

printf("Not Found!");
return 1;
```